# Filtering Data based on the selected item from a checkbox not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react code, I have a default data that display anytime there's no checkbox checked but when there's a checked value, the data should update and return another data based on the checked value. but what I have at the moment is not giving me what I expect. Kindly help me check what I'm doing wrong.

what I'm expecting is for the table to return another table with the checked value...anywhere the checked value is found in the table else, if not found return default data

my sandbox [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-zhukovsky-vo8h7?file=/src/App.js)

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DefaultData from "./DefaultData";

export default function App() {
  const [isselected, setisselected] = useState([]);

  const OnChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    const ischecked = e.target.checked;
    if (ischecked) {
      setisselected([...isselected, e.target.value]);
    } else {
      const index = isselected.indexOf(e.target.value);
      isselected.splice(index, 1);
      setisselected(isselected);
    }

    console.log(isselected);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(isselected, "value selected");
  }, [isselected]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>
        Filters applied:{" "}
        {isselected.map((i) => (
          <span>{i}</span>
        ))}
      </span>

      <div className="first-search">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="input-1"
          value="Lastsevendays"
          name="last_seven"
          id="1"
          onChange={OnChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="">Last 7 days</label>
      </div>

      <div className="first-search">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="input-1"
          name="last24"
          value="last_24"
          id="2"
          onChange={OnChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="">Last 24 hours</label>

        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Header1</th>
              <th>Header2</th>
              <th>Header3</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {
              !isselected.length ? DefaultData.filter(x => x === '3 days ago').map((item, index)=>{
                <tr>
                <td>{item.includes}</td>
                <td>{item.date_listed}</td>
                <td>{item.id}</td>
              </tr>
              }) : DefaultData.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{item.distance}</td>
                    <td>{item.date_listed}</td>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })



            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing an error in the sandbox url - Default is undefined. Are you planning to correct it?

Comment: Let me do that now

Comment: Just should write what you expect from the code

Comment: what I'm expecting is for the table to return another table with the checked value...anywhere the checked value is found in the table else, if not found return default data @MarioNikolaus

Comment: Why do you have this in your render `.filter(x => x === '3 days ago')`

Comment: There is no conditional rendering in your sandbox...

Comment: Just using that as a sample incase such value is checked @MarioNikolaus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really never apply your filters, so that's why they don't work.

Your code should look something like this(this is negative branch of ternary operator on L71)

```
DefaultData
  .filter(item => isSelected.includes(item.date_listed))
  .map((item) => (
    <tr key={item.id}>
      <td>{item.distance}</td>
      <td>{item.date_listed}</td>
      <td>{item.id}</td>
    </tr>
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you @MarioNikolaus I tried your code but still not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working, update your question please with latest code

Answer (score 1):

3 things :

### 1 - You make a mistake in your `onChange` function

You mutate the array `isselected` and send it as argument to `setisselected`.

```
isselected.splice(index, 1);
  setisselected(isselected);
```

It is considered to be the same object as the already existing value `isselected` and so it is not updated.

You should not mutate this array directly, but manipulate a shallow copy and send it as value. For example :

```
const newSelection = Array.from(isselected);
newSelection.splice(index, 1);
setisselected(newSelection);
```

### 2 - You're not filtering correctly

`DefaultData` is an array of object with `date_listed` properties you want to filter on, so you to do it like this :

```
DefaultData.filter(x => x.date_listed === '3 days ago')
```

### 3 - bracket parenthesis mismatch

You used brackets instead of parenthesis here :

```
.map((item, index)=>(
            <tr>
            <td>{item.includes}</td>
            <td>{item.date_listed}</td>
            <td>{item.id}</td>
          </tr>
          ))
```

Comment: But do I still need the index @JulienLemaitre but I'm still not getting what I needed

Comment: Thank you everyone. It's working now